# Change of definitons

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to revive some old software but the problem is that the software was written in 2003 with MC and windows Iostream Header files have changed from that times `iostream.h` to `iostream`.

So this software had a 3D matrix Library which had function something like this

```
friend ostream& operator<< (ostream&, const CMatrix3D<T>&);
```

this function was no more compatable with `iostream` so I changed it to:

```
friend bool operator<< (std::ostream&, const CMatrix3D<T>&);
```

but now at one place where this function was previously called as:

```
friend ostream& operator << (ostream& os, block* bl)
{
vec_3d p1 = bl->points[0]->value();
vec_3d p2 = bl->points[6]->value();
os << "Diagonal points: " << p1 << " " << p2;
return os;

}
```

and then I changed it to:

```
friend bool operator << (std::ostream& os, block* bl)
{
vec_3d p1 = bl->points[0]->value();
vec_3d p2 = bl->points[6]->value();
os << "Diagonal points: " << p1 << " " << p2;
return os;
}
```

giving me these errors:

```
error C2297: '<<' : illegal, right operand has type 'const char [2]'

error C2678: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand
operand of type 'int' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

Can someone suggest me a way out?

Comment: What errors do you get with original function definition?

Comment: Why did you change the return type of `<<` operator to `bool`??? Regardless of any other problems, this change alone will ruin the code.

Comment: If you have updates to your question please edit your question, don't post an "answer". If you have another question please ask a separate question, don't post an "answer".

Answer (score 1):

The reason that that the `operator<<` on ostreams has a return type of `ostream&` is so that it can be chained, to call as shown in your example implementations:

```
os << "Diagonal points: " << p1 << " " << p2;
```

This is the standard behavior of that operator, and a lot of code will rely on it, so it's a bad idea to have it return something else such as the `bool` that you changed it to.  It should always return `std::ostream&`.

That should fix at least some of your problems.  It is not clear without seeing the rest of your code, and knowing exactly which line the compiler is complaining about, whether that is all of the problem or not.

Comment: He will also need << operator for vec_3d, and it should be taking const vec_3d& (probably non-const now).

Comment: yes i tried that stuff and it worked and now new error came up

Answer (score 0):

To remove whitespace from an input stream these days, you use the `std::ws` input manipulator. 
i.e.

```
fp >> ws;
```

[MSDN Reference for std::ws](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db4fefz1.aspx).

Comment: no its not working as fp is already defined by fsteam (in the first line)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment -- the snippet I posted isn't redefining fp; it's just using it in an expression which reads and discards whitespace characters.